# "Error: cannot set property appendChild() of null

Tags: javascript, html, html5, funções, dom

No meu código eu fiz uma função para criar um botão e logo após o usuário clicar nele o botão e o outro conteúdo alterado são apagados.

Eu consegui chegar nesse ponto, porém botão fica no final do `body`. Para resolver isso precisei usar a função `elementoPai.appendChild(node);`, o que seria o seguinte resultado no meu código:

```
var pai = document.getElementById("form1");

var b1fechar = document.createElement("BUTTON");

b1fechar.setAttribute("id", "b1fechar");

b1fechar = document.getElementById("b1fechar");

pai.appendChild(b1fechar);
```

***Esse seria a parte interessante do código***.

Javascript inteiro aqui embaixo (arquivo .js):

```
var pai = document.getElementById("form1");

//Funções básicas de texto para output visual no site
function GetMoveInfo()
{
    var ictext = document.getElementById("ictext").innerHTML = iceBeam.info;
    var b1fechar = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    b1fechar.setAttribute("id", "b1fechar");
    b1fechar.addEventListener("click", closeIcebeam, true);
    b1fechar.innerHTML = "Fechar";
    pai.appendChild(b1fechar);
    //document.createTextNode(""); para criar texto para outras ocasiões.
   
};
```

***Tudo funciona até a linha 8.***

HTML do site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Em construção</title>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1">
<input type="radio" id="icebeam" name="mov" value="icebeam">
  <label for="icebeam" >Icebeam</label><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="GetMoveInfo()" id="showicebeam">+Informações</button><br>
  <p id="ictext"></p>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" id="flamethrower" name="mov" value="flamethrower">
  <label for="icebeam">Flamethrower</label><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aceito sugestões para melhoria do código também, obg.

Comment: `b1fechar = document.getElementById("b1fechar");` pq atribuiu um valor a um elemento que já tinha valor, e ainda nem foi adicionado ao DOM? isso vai resultar null, o `getElementById` vai ler documentos que fazem parte do DOM, e o seu ainda não foi inserido nesse exemplo. Fora isso, na function `GetMoveInfo()`, onde foi definida a variável "pai"? Aproveite e remove a tag `java`, pq esse código nada tem de java, use `javascript`

Comment: @RicardoPontual não tem a tag java... Tem apenas a tag javascript. Vou rever esse erro que você comentou, obg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perdão, porém a sua pergunta ficou bem confusa, e só analisando o código não ficou claro qual era sua intenção. Não leve a mal, provavelmente você está começando, tente usar nomes de variáveis e funções mais claros e comentar o código explicando o que cada bloco faz.

Eu fiz uma versão do seu código reformulada, o resultado é o que imaginei que fosse sua intenção, espero ter ajudado e que você aprenda muito ainda nesse mundo da programação.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Em construção</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <div>
        <span>First Option</span>
        <input type="radio" id="icebeam" value="firstoption">
        <button type="button" id="more" class="more-1" onclick="showContent(this)">More</button>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:10px;">
        <span>First Option</span>
        <input type="radio" id="icebeam" value="firstoption">
        <button type="button" id="more" class="more-2" onclick="showContent(this)">More</button>
    </div>

    <div id="father">
    
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const more = document.getElementById('more');
    function showContent(e){
        if(e.classList.contains('more-1')){
            document.getElementById('father').innerHTML = '<button id="delete">Deletar</button>' + ' Conteudo do 

Texto';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('father').innerHTML = '<button id="delete">Deletar</button>' + ' Conteudo do 

Texto';
        };
        document.getElementById('delete').addEventListener('click', deleteContent, false);

    }

    function deleteContent() {
            document.getElementById('father').innerHTML = '';
        };

    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Esse código vai verificar a classe CSS do botão para saber qual conteúdo exibir dentro da classe Pai.

Comment: Olá, já ia fazer uma semana e ninguém respondia, imaginei que havia algo errado :/ . Colocando a sua resposta aqui vi que a ideia que eu queria era exatamente isso, eu vou dar uma mexida agora a partir dela. Sim, eu estou começando mesmo, acabei de fazer dois cursos a uma semana atrás. Muito obrigado pela ajuda :)
@LucasBezerra